# CD with Java spring profiles

Tags: spring, docker, maven, gitlab-ci, cicd

I have an application based on java spring in kubernetes. For multipule environments I use spring profiles. But I need to rebuild my app for each environment using maven+docker to get the right config and push it into kubernetes.

Here are my  lines in pipeline:

```
 - mvn clean -Dspring.profiles.active=$ENV_PROFILE package
 - DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build 
      --build-arg ARTIFACT=$ARTIFACT 
      --build-arg SERVER_PORT=$SERVER_PORT 
      --build-arg ENV_PROFILE=$ENV_PROFILE
```

Can I build an app once and push it to all environments?

Comment: that would depend on what ENV_PROFILE does for your docker build, right?

Comment: No, you should build your app once and deploy it to many environments. Spring profiles aren't too helpful in a k8s environment -- they're primarily meant for previous-generation platforms like PCF. You just want to inject environment or property files into your container and have your app read them at startup to determine its environment. And, all environments should essentially be identical anyway (with the possible exception of dev).

Comment: @eis I guess that
ENTRYPOINT java -Xms$HEAP_MIN -Xmx$HEAP_MAX -jar /app/$ARTIFACT --server.port=$SERVER_PORT --spring.profiles.active=$ENV_PROFILE

Comment: @Software Engineer 
So, i need a bind mount host <-> container into pod(container) and push config in 
bind folder. Secondly i need modify app to read config. And add some CD. Maybe you know some good tools for manage property files into container for java?
I appreciate your time!

Comment: You can do it with env vars if you wanted to, but spring works easiest with property files. You do not want to bind mount the host though, you should take a look at kubernetes config maps: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/. You can basically mount a config that has been stored in k8s. So, if your dev db is at https://dev-db:5432 and your test db is at https://test-db:5432 you would put them in your config map in a field called something like local-db and mount a property file that pulls out that field.

Comment: Note: You do not need to update your `ENTRYPOINT` value to pass in a profile. Spring will natively read the profiles from the `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE` environment variable, even if you set a value in an `application.properties` file. In terms of configurations, environment variables are higher in the priority queue and file-based configurations, so anything set in your environment variable will override your application.properties.